# images taken with iphone appearing sideways when displayed in desktop browser

Tags: node.js, image, base64

I'm building a feature in my app that makes use of input type file like this...

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.loadFile} accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

So when this input is activated on a phone it launches the phone camera.  The resulting image is then saved in the file input.  I then use HTML5 to base64 encode that image to a string and send it up to the server in an async post.

Here is the problem...

I then display these images taken by the camera in a list in a different part of the app.  When I view these photos on the same device it looks fine.  However, if I load the application into a desktop browser like chrome, the images appear sideways.

All the research I've done points to the fact that the phone is assuming I am taking a landscape picture when I'm really trying to take a portrait.  It makes sense then that it would be displayed sideway, but it doesn't explain to me when it appears differently in different browsers.  Also, the solution that I keep on hearing is that if I want to fix this, I need to open the image in a third party desktop app like photoshop, rotate it and save it.  But that in the context I mentioned above is obviously not possible?

Is there a way to fix the orientation of the camera in the app?  Or any other way to avoid this silly problem?

Thanks